# How do I set up the runner plugin in Launchy to create an RDP connection with a server argument in Windows?

Tags: windows, launchy

I would think that adding an entry to "Runner" with the following values would allow me to enter rdp as the command, tab to begin entering user input and type in the name of a server I wish to rdp to...

```
Name               rdp
Program            C:\WINDOWS\system32\mstsc.exe
Arguments          /v:$$
```

But, this doesn't seem to work. Whenever I try to execute the command in Launchy, it ignores the "/v:" part of the argument. Instead, I get an "Invalid connection file specified" error. Is there a different syntax I should be using for the Argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run Launchy 2.6 beta 2. Runner config is following:
name: cons
command: c:\windows\system32\mstsc.exe
arguments: /v:$$ /admin

entering of IP address works fine. Probably you had earlier command without "/v:" and after modification tried immediately without rescanning the catalog...

Comment: I think you're right. I tried creating a new command with a different name and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue keeps getting me everytime I rebuild so thought I would update here as well.

Drop the full path to `MSTSC.exe`

I'm using Launchy 2.6 Beta 2 on Win 8.0 and if I use the full path I just get the GUI `/?` output. Drop the run path to just `mstsc.exe` and everything works as I expect it to.

```
Name : rdc 
Program : mstsc.exe
Args : /v:$$ /Multimon
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.